# Problem with switch-statement "too many characters int the char constant"

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have some problem with the switch-statement and I don't know how to resolve it:

```
    string phrase;

    cout << "enter a phrase:\n";
    getline(cin, phrase);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        switch (phrase[i])
        {
        case '-----':
            cout << "0";
            break;
        }
    }
```

It gives me an error that says "too many characters int the char constant".
Can somebody tell me how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `'-----'` to proper thing. What do you want to do?

Comment: [`'-----'` is.. an int](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) (s"" (6)), you cannot switch on string though.

Comment: 1. You cannot compare to a string in a case statement.
2. You are switching on a character, why are you trying to compare it to a string.
3. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: c++ is not javascript

Comment: You can't switch on a string in C++. Use if-then-else chain.

Answer (score 1):

```
string phrase;
int sum=0;
cout << "enter a phrase:\n";
getline(cin, phrase);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
{   
    
    switch (phrase[i])
    {
    case '-':sum+=1;
        if (sum%5==0)
        cout << "0";
        break;
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: the fact is that i want to create a program that i can input morse code and give me the correct translation but some character or number are 5/6 digit long and also if i use if-then-else chain i give me error

Comment: You can use a variable to track a running total of the character '-'. Whenever it detects a character '-', increment it. Then you can test this variable with if condition and display a '0' when variable holds a specific value of your choice.

Comment: it will be a mess because there are a lot of of option also because some of the number/character have the same number of - and . only the position change